# Windows Phone 8 push notification without MPNS?

Tags: websphere, windows-phone-8, mqtt

We already have a push notification system that consists of Websphere MQTT for server side, and Paho client for Android side. We now want to extend its scope to Windows Phone 8, but as far as I understood from Microsoft' s documentations, it is necessary to use MPNS in order to implement notifications in WP8. 
My question is, do we have any workaround to use our existing notification system(Websphere MQTT) without using any part of MPNS?

We wrote .NET client that is working perfectly with our system, and I believe it can get to work in WP8 platform after some modifications, somehow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, do we have any workaround to use our existing notification system(Websphere MQTT) without using any part of MPNS?

No. Microsoft require applications to go through the Microsoft Push Notification Hub to ensure both privacy and avoid 3rd party services going crazy.

Given that a PUSH notification executes a OS call to show a toast, update a tile, or the likes, it's important that the notification isn't abused, as it otherwise could cause extensive battery use, or higher phone bills for the owner of the device.

But for example, it's a formality to integrate a Windows Azure service into MPNS, so I don't see why you would attempt to create a work-around, unless you don't think your application will be certified?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually what i meant was that, we just want to reuse our existing mq infrastructure and we don' t want our messages to go through any other environment that is completely out of our control. Workaround was the wrong word, i meant: is there any other way to send notifications like people do in Android, iOS, etc. with a MQTT backend? I just want to send a push message from our servers to the device, and do it without relying on any other existence.